# Customized validation Message : Laravel 5.2.15

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following code written in Request class under Rules method.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'Currency' => 'required|max:5|min:2|composite_unique:tblcurrency,CurrencyCode',
        'CurrencyCode' => 'required|max:5|min:1',
    ];
}
```

This works fine. Only issue is, when the validation fails, I get the following message..

> validation.composite_unique

**What i tried so far?**

After writing the below code, still I am getting the same error string.

```
public function messages () {
    return [
        'validation.composite_unique'  => 'Duplicate Country and code combination found.',
    ];
}
```

**Question**: Can we customize the Validation message to make it look more user friendly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public function messages () {
    return [
        'Currency.composite_unique'  => 'Duplicate Country and code combination found.',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it worked. Below is the correct way to customize the message.

```
public function messages () {
    return [
        'composite_unique'  => 'Duplicate Country and code combination found.',
    ];
}
```